# sort array numerically only

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is the array

```
$array = array(
   'list[P] = 1',
   'list[A] = 1',
   'list[F] = 2',
   'list[B] = 1'
);
```

This is the output I want

```
[0] => list[P] = 1
[1] => list[A] = 1
[2] => list[B] = 1
[3] => list[F] = 2
```

notice `list[P]` remains at the top because it is the first with value 1. So only numeric sorting

Comment: Do you want "list" to be an array? Or is the "list[A]" a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try taking a look at [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

As you are trying to sort a specific part of the value, then you need to write your own comparator, and therefore the only method available is the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

The uksort function takes two attributes, the array and the method name that you wish to use to do your comparison. You then write this method, which takes two values as a parameters, and return a true of false, depending on whether it is greater than or less than.

Therefore, you would have to substring the values coming in, to only compare the numbers.

The following code sample seems to work

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = substr($a, -1);
    $b = substr($b, -1);
    return $a >= $b;
}

$array = array(
   'list[P] = 1',
   'list[A] = 1',
   'list[F] = 2',
   'list[B] = 1'
);

usort($array, "cmp");

var_dump($array);
```

The same code, only using PHP's anonymous function:

```
$array = array(
   'list[P] = 1',
   'list[A] = 1',
   'list[F] = 2',
   'list[B] = 1'
);

usort(
   $array,
   function ($a, $b){
      $a = substr($a, -1);
      $b = substr($b, -1);
      return $a >= $b;
   }
);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: @Codemwnci: Why am I not getting the above result?

Comment: @dany slightly misread your question, I have updated so it should now make sense!

Comment: Shouldn't that be usort because you are sorting by value? Anyway, the problem with usort (or uksort) is that if the comparison is equal, the elements are undefined...

Comment: Note:
If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

Apparently, this "note" is not clear enough... I tested and got an arranged array with no problems...

Comment: @Codemwnci: The alphabetical order is maintained until the number at list[F] is changed to 1. list[F] goes to the top of the list. Why is this?

Comment: This is my output - array(4) { [0]=> string(11) "list[P] = 1" [1]=> string(11) "list[A] = 1" [2]=> string(11) "list[B] = 1" [3]=> string(11) "list[F] = 2" }

Comment: @Codemwnci: Change list[F]=2 to list[F]=1

Comment: Odd, that is not what mine is doing.

Comment: @Codemnwci: I didn't mean it chanegs to 2, I meant YOU change it to 2 and you will see that list[F]=1 starts at the top

Comment: Ah, sorry. Maybe it is the undefined nature of equal members that Ibrahim has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to preserve records or keys with equal values in the same order they were input into the sort in the software you are writing then you would need a sort algorithm or method which is categorised as 'stable'. This limits the types of sort methods available to a programmer in any one country or a region within it in order to conform to the relevant rules.